# Appending csv rows while adding characters from lines from file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I have a .csv file that I am creating, and it is being created by iterating through an input file. My current code for the specific column this question is about looks like this:

```
input_filename = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]
f = open(sys.argv[3]).read()

list.append(("A B", f[0:2], "numeric", "A B"))
```

For the portion of the code 'f[0:2]', rather than having it append the first few characters of f as a whole file (which obviously makes it append the first few characters every time it is appended), I want it to append [0:2] for the next line in f every time the loop is executed. I have tried:

```
list.append(("A B", f.line[0:2], "numeric", "A B"))
```

and other similar approaches, to no avail. I hope this question is clear - if not, I am happy to clarify. Any suggestions for putting this stipulation into this append line are appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little hard for me to guess what you're trying to do here, but is this something like what you're looking for?

Contents of data.txt

```
abc
def
```

The code:

```
# I'm simply replacing your names so I can test this more easily
input_filename = 'input.txt'
output_filename = 'output.txt'
data_filename = 'data.txt'
transformed_data = []
with open(data_filename) as df:
    for line in df:
        # remove surrounding whitespace- assuming you want this
        line = line.strip()
        if line:  # make sure there's non-whitespace characters left
            transformed_data.append(("A B", line[0:2], "numeric", "A B"))

print(transformed_data)
# produces
# [('A B', 'ab', 'numeric', 'A B'), ('A B', 'de', 'numeric', 'A B')]
```

If you're working with .csv files, I highly recommend the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library that comes with Python. Let it handle encoding and formatting for you.

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fix the issue, and will study the csv library. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BigBlue Great! If my answer helped you, please accept it so I can reap the probably useless but oh-so-satisfying points. If you're new to Python, I recommend [this page on the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/). I've saved a lot of time knowing what's in there and I've learned a lot reading the source code to individual modules (usually linked at the top of each page).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Your answer has officially been accepted!